# Jenkins: npm EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have the following a simple `sudo npm install` which keeps on failing on EACCESS error:

[image]

I have already tried the following on the server:

```
sudo chown -R jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/
sudo setfacl -R -m user:jenkins:rwx /var/lib/jenkins/workspace
```

But unfortunetly nothing seems to work.

Would love to hear some suggestions for what might cause the problem.

Thanks

Comment: See if this addresses your issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859018/cannot-install-node-sass-therefore-cannot-install-gulp-sass

Comment: It concerns more with global npm packages. In my case this is a local npm package trying to be written into a jenkins owned directory.

Comment: Check if this can help you => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553395/error-eacces-permission-denied-rmdir-on-jenkins

Answer (score 5):

Actually, what helped me use Jenkins with sudo rights for Ubuntu Linux was the following command:

```
sudo chown -R jenkins folderName
sudo setfacl -R -m user:jenkins:rwx folderName
```

also you need to browse to the Jenkins install in Ubuntu at

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace
```

Assuming you're in Home folder, you'll have to go down two levels.

```
cd ..
cd ..
```

then

```
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace
```

then

```
sudo chown -R jenkins folderName
sudo setfacl -R -m user:jenkins:rwx folderName
```

This fixed my "run jenkins as root" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `.npm-global` to the proper owner. I had a similar issue while deploying using Jenkins. The `.npm-global` folder owner was Jenkins but all the subfolder under that had root as owner. Then I changed the owner using the below command

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu .npm-global
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue appeared in combination with docker images while building.
I had to set the `npm_config_cache=npm-cache` and `HOME=.` environment variables so npm uses the current directory to build.

Jenkinsfile:

```
docker.withRegistry('https://my_registry/', 'docker_user') {
    docker.image('node-agent:node-14').inside {
        withEnv([
            /* Override the npm cache directory */
            /* Reset Home dir */
            'npm_config_cache=npm-cache',
            'HOME=.',
        ]) {
            stage('NPM Build') {
                sh "rm -rf node_modules || true" // removing node_modules if existing.
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm run build'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your question is a duplicate, but people have problems with installing node-sass.

The easiest way to fix your specific problem is:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```